# No notification sound of google talk on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, flash, chromium, gtalk

everyone. I am using Ubuntu 12.04 and chromium. The problem I am facing is that there is no sound notifications of the incoming message. After doing some search on internet, I found that may be this is because the flash player does not work properly.

However, I can see videos on youtube and some other video sites. I can even see the ads present on the websites. I have found a threads   ([How do I get adobe flash working in Chrome or Chromium on Ringtail?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/313646/how-do-i-get-adobe-flash-working-in-chrome-or-chromium-on-ringtail)) in the answer of which describe the exact situation I am facing. That is: on one hand, the official website tells that you have no flash player installed; on the other hand, it can tell your installed flash player version.

I don't know how to fix this because the answer provided ask to delete .tmp file in home directory, which I didn't find exist.

By the way, the notification sound functions well on firefox.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to right click on the flash object, select global settings, and then on the right hand side, it'll say "[Peer-Assisted Networking Panel](http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager09.html)" and enable each site. I have to do this in ubuntu 12.04 with webcam toys for chromium, so I figured it'll help you with another website flash related issue.

Comment: thanks for replying, my mouse can't click  on the option, always allow or any other. simply no response